# Stop currently running container process without killing the container

Tags: docker

I'm developing app with few people and decided to fully dockerize dev environment (for easier deployment and collaboration). I did it by making super short Dockerfile.dev for services such as this one

```
FROM node:18

COPY ./frontend/dev_autostart.sh .
```

Each service has it's own dev_autostart.sh script that waits for volume to be mounted, then depending on the service it installs dependencies and runs it in dev mode (f.e. 'npm i && npm run dev').
My issue with this setup is that installing dependencies is harder because to do that i'd need to stop container and install dependencies using my machine or change docker entrypoint to something like 'tail -F anything'.
My ideal workflow would be

1. 'docker attach $containerName'
2. Somehow stop current process without killing the container
3. Do stuff
4. Rerun process manually (cargo run . / npm run dev)

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried `kill`ing the process?

Comment: @mustaccio just checked it, my autostart script launches 'npm run dev'. If I kill node process inside container from another shell it stops whole container.